# import flask on wsgi virtual host fails

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

Having the following directory structure and setup:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── flask
├── myapp.wsgi
├── run.py
├── run.pyc
└── tmp
```

**myapp.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
#sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/otherStuff/myApp/")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

#from app import app
from app import app as application
application.secret_key = 'xyz'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

**vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName local.myapp.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/otherStuff/myApp/myappwsgi
        <Directory /var/www/otherStuff/myApp/app>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        #Alias /static /var/www/otherStuff/myApp/static
        #<Directory /var/www/otherStuff/myApp/static>
        #       Order allow,deny
        #       Allow from all
        #</Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/myApp-error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/www/logs/myApp-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I can't seem to figure out, why the `Flask` dependency is not loaded and therefore, it fails to run

```
mod_wsgi (pid=19668): Target WSGI script '/var/www/otherStuff/myApp/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://local.myapp.com/
mod_wsgi (pid=19668): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/otherStuff/myApp/myapp.wsgi'., referer: http://local.myapp.com/
Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://local.myapp.com/
  File "/var/www/otherStuff/myApp/myapp.wsgi", line 8, in <module>, referer: http://local.myapp.com/
    from app import app as application, referer: http://local.myapp.com/
  File "/var/www/otherStuff/myApp/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>, referer: http://local.myapp.com/
    from flask import Flask, referer: http://local.myapp.com/
ImportError: No module named flask, referer: http://local.myapp.com/
```

**UPDATE**

`flask` is the virtualenv:

```
flask/
├── bin
├── include
├── lib
├── lib64 -> /home/alexb/www/otherStuff/faqColab/flask/lib
├── local
└── pyvenv.cfg
```

Comment: Have you installed flask? How, where?

Comment: @DanielRoseman ummm `├── flask`; it's there

Comment: Instead of manually copying anything on your project folder, I suggest you learn to install Flask as a Python package and configure virtualenv for your installation - this way you can use Flask and any other Python packages using standard Python tools. The official guide how to install Python packages: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: mmm... that is the virtual env, nothing is copied manually :\ `virtualenv flask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell mod_wsgi how to find packages in your virtual environment. I'm not positive I have your folder structure exactly correct, but it should be something like this.

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/otherStuff/myApp:/var/www/otherStuff/myApp/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```